# runs properly in netbeans but not in command prompt

Tags: java

Edit: I'm not allowed to use scanner. I know, its better.

The purpose of this program is to accept a leap four digit integer from the user and determine whether or not it is a leap year, inform the user of the result, and then prompt to reset the program to accept another entry. If the user enters a date before the year 1582 AD, it will be denied.

```
public class RevisedLeapYear {
    public static void main(String args[])
    throws java.io.IOException {

    char restartChoice = 'y';
    int readCh, year=0, i;
    boolean isLeapYear;

    while(restartChoice == 'y' || restartChoice == 'Y'){
        System.out.print("Enter target year: ");
        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++)//start for
        {
            readCh = (int)System.in.read();
            switch(i) //start switch
            {//converts in to 4 digits
                case 0: year = (int)((readCh - 48) * 1000); break;
                case 1: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 100); break;
                case 2: year = year + (int) ((readCh - 48) * 10); break;
                case 3: year = year + (int) (readCh - 48);
            }//end switch
    }//end for
        isLeapYear = ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0));
                if(isLeapYear == true && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive!");
            }
                else if(isLeapYear == false && year > 1581){
                System.out.println(year + " is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate.");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("There are no leap years before 1582!");
            }
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the carriage return in the buffer
    readCh = System.in.read(); // Clear the linefeed in the buffer

    System.out.print("Reset program? y/n \n");
    restartChoice=(char)System.in.read(); //Clears restart choice from the buffer.
    year=(int)System.in.read(); //Clears year from the buffer.

    }              
}//End main
}//End class
```

The problem I am running in to is that in command prompt, no matter what the second entry is, it will always say its less than 1582. I had this same problem when I developed it in netbeans, and fixed it by clearing the buffer with "year=(int)System.in.read();". The program ran without a hitch after that, but now when running it with command prompt, the problem repeats.

This is the result of trying to run 3 iterations of the program using the values 2916, 1900, and 1432.

```
///// In Netbeans

Enter target year: 2916
2916 is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive!

Reset program? y/n 
y
Enter target year: 1900
1900 is not a Leap Year... how unfortunate.

Reset program? y/n 
y
Enter target year: 1432
There are no leap years before 1582!

Reset program? y/n 
n
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 49 seconds)

///// end of program

///// In command prompt

Enter target year: 2916
2916 is a Leap Year! What a time to be alive1
Reset program? y/n
y
Enter target year: 1900
There are no leap years before 1582!
Reset program? y/n
y

///// End of program
```

There are a few things wrong.
1. It always thinks the user entered a # < 1582 on the second run of the program.

2. In the netbeans run there are spaces after the result of whether or not the entry was a leap year where the user must press a key to continue to the reset prompt, for some reason command prompt bypasses by this. It isn't necessarily a problem, in fact it is better, but it might be linked to the problem.
3. The program ends after the second iteration no matter what is entered in the reset prompt.

Comment: You should consider using a `Scanner` for user input.

Comment: I am required to not use scanner.

Answer (score 0):

can you add `a System.out.println(readCh);` after `readCh = (int)System.in.read();`

I don't understand why you have the line :

`year=(int)System.in.read(); //Clears year from the buffer.`

You can clear year with a year=0;

Comment: When I do that I get this https://i.gyazo.com/bad3acc90bdeb392c719e814c697acfb.png

Comment: Their is a 10 char who is put as the first char of the year ( it's a new Line char) during the writting of the 1900 year. consequently, the second year should be something like 190 or 152 .
try to understand why their is a new line char here. ( I suspect the line : year=(int)System.in.read())

Comment: Nothing changed when I did that. The reason year=(int)System.in.read()) is there is because for some reason doing year=0 will stick it as 0, and thus cause the same error.

Comment: a new theory : in the run, after the reset, not use the enter key to pass this line. Use any letter key (in some environnement, the new line is not one but two char).